# Calling the value of a variable as a property of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm writing a command handler for this app, which uses a list of nested JSON key/values as a sort of directory for executing commands. (The file's structure is still a work in progress):

```
{
    "commands": {
        "category1": {
            "command1_c1": {
                "alias": ["c1c1alias1", "c1c1alias2", "c1c1alias3", "c1c1alias4"]
            },
            "command2_c1": {
                "alias": ["c1c2alias1", "c1c2alias2"]
            },
            "command3_c1": {
                "alias": ["c1c3alias1", "c1c3alias2"]
            }
        },
        "category2": {
            "command1_c2": {
                "alias": ["c2c1alias1", "c2c1alias2"]
            },
            "command2_c2": {
                "alias": ["c2c2alias1"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This JSON file is "required" in my JavaScript file:

```
const jsonCommands = require("./commands/commands.json");
```

I wrote this code, which is supposed to iterate through each level like so, and locate a command based on the user's input:

```
for (var listedCategory in jsonCommands.commands) {
    console.log(`listedCategory: ${listedCategory}`);
    for (var listedCommand in jsonCommands.commands.listedCategory) {
        console.log(`listedCommand: ${listedCommand}`);
        if (listedCommand === userCommand) {
            console.log(`success in finding command ${userCommand}`);
        }
    }
}
```

This code above does not log anything in the second `for-in` loop. The return of the code written above is this (and no error is thrown):

```
listedCategory: lookup
listedCategory: other
```

Here is another version of the code, which does similar, but also accesses the `alias` array. I doubt it would return any array values right now, though:

```
Object.keys(jsonCommands).forEach(category => {
    console.log(`Category: ${category}`);
    Object.keys(jsonCommands.category).forEach(command => {
        console.log(`Command: ${command}`);
        if (command === userCommand) {
            console.log(`A command was recognized: \`${userCommand}\``);
        } else {
            Object.keys(jsonCommands.category.command).forEach(aliasCommand => {
                console.log(`aliasCommand: ${aliasCommand}`);
                if (aliasCommand === userCommand) {
                    console.log(`A command alias was recognized: \`${userCommand}\``);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This code above does not function either. This is the error that is thrown:

```
Object.keys(jsonCommands.category).forEach(command => {
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Now, there are two problems I see here, one in each example. (I mainly posted the second example to show what else I had tried, albeit.) The problem in the first code example is that it may be trying to access the variable name as a JSON key rather than the variable name that is assigned in the callback, such as in the statement `jsonCommands.commands.listedCategory`, making the returned value undefined, which is why it won't iterate.

I'm not sure what's happening in the second code example. I suspect that the reason for the thrown error is similar, though - telling Object.keys to access a value that is undefined.

I'm sure that the first solution would work fine if that bug is fixed, however. How would I go about making the value of the variable `listedCategory`, which is declared on callback, to be used as a property of the JSON object?

Apologies if this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***TL:DR;***

You need to use `[]` when you want to access property using variable

```js
let jsonCommands = {"commands": {"category1": {"command1_c1": {"alias": ["c1c1alias1", "c1c1alias2", "c1c1alias3", "c1c1alias4"]},"command2_c1": {"alias": ["c1c2alias1", "c1c2alias2"]},"command3_c1": {"alias": ["c1c3alias1", "c1c3alias2"]}},"category2": {"command1_c2": {"alias": ["c2c1alias1", "c2c1alias2"]},"command2_c2": {"alias": ["c2c2alias1"]}}}}

let userCommand = 'command2_c2'

for (var listedCategory in jsonCommands.commands) {
    console.log(`listedCategory: ${listedCategory}`);
    for (var listedCommand in jsonCommands.commands[listedCategory]) {
        console.log(`listedCommand: ${listedCommand}`);
        if (listedCommand === userCommand) {
            console.log(`success in finding command ${userCommand}`);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your first extract of code like this:

````
let userCommand = 'command3_c1'

for (const listedCategory in jsonCommands.commands) {
    console.log(`listedCategory: ${listedCategory}`);
    for (const listedCommand in jsonCommands.commands[listedCategory]) {
        console.log(`listedCommand: ${listedCommand}`);
        if (listedCommand === userCommand) {
            console.log(`success in finding command ${userCommand}`);
        }
    }
}```

And the out is:

```Category: commands
Command: category1
aliasCommand: command1_c1
aliasCommand: command2_c1
aliasCommand: command3_c1
A command alias was recognized: `command3_c1`
Command: category2
aliasCommand: command1_c2
aliasCommand: command2_c2
````

The second:

```
let userCommand = 'command3_c1'

Object.keys(jsonCommands).forEach(category => {
    console.log(`Category: ${category}`)
    Object.keys(jsonCommands[category]).forEach(command => {
        console.log(`Command: ${command}`)
        if (command === userCommand) {
            console.log(`A command was recognized: \`${userCommand}\``)
        } else {
            Object.keys(jsonCommands[category][command]).forEach(aliasCommand => {
                console.log(`aliasCommand: ${aliasCommand}`)
                if (aliasCommand === userCommand) {
                    console.log(`A command alias was recognized: \`${userCommand}\``)
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

And the out is:

```
Command: category1
aliasCommand: command1_c1
aliasCommand: command2_c1
aliasCommand: command3_c1
A command alias was recognized: `command3_c1`
Command: category2
aliasCommand: command1_c2
aliasCommand: command2_c2
```

Comment: This answer works just like the other one. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to understand in greater depth the objects in javascript you can read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors